# Connect two networks to share resources

Tags: lan

We have two offices with separate routers and Internet connections. Is it possible to connect them with a LAN cable so they can share files?

The first router is at gateway 192.168.100.1 the second is at 192.168.101.1.
From what I read I will need to assign static routes in the routers. Is that all I need to do?

Comment: it is actually based on your network size. you can have a switch network. and based on your traffic, connect switch(es?) to router. it depends on your primary usage. do you have heavy intra-office traffic? then switch networking is better, but if you want to connect the offices, just to be connected, you can use other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the perspective of the network, you need the physical connection between the two routers on a common subnet, but you also need the routers to share routes, either through a common routing protocol, or by configuring static routes. You need to make sure there are no overlapping routes, too.

From the perspective of the computers connected to the networks, you may have a problem with DHCP. You will need to make sure that the routers only connect to each other on their own link, not the LAN of the other router. When a host requests DHCP, it will use the first DHCP response, which may end up being the wrong DHCP server if the two separate networks are connected via layer-2, not layer-3.

Comment: Hi, late comment, I've been thinking about this and would it work if I put the two networks on same subnet, and then set the default gateway manually, so some of the pc's use internet from router one and others will use internet from the second router.

Comment: You need to be careful about the two DHCP servers assigning the same address to two different PCs. You could have something like one DHCP server assign from `.10` to `.40` and the other assign from `.50` to `.80`. You wouldn't even need to manually set the gateway, just let the fastest (usually closest) DHCP server assign.

Comment: So I can use both internets on different pc's and access network shares from the different gateways?